# error: ‘void DoubleMeanVar::operator/=()’ must have exactly one argument

Tags: c++

I have this code :

```
class DoubleMeanVar{
    protected:
        double m;
        double v;
    public:
        DoubleMeanVar(double x=0) : m(x), v(0) {}
        DoubleMeanVar& operator+=(double x);
        void operator/=(){m = 1; v = 0;}
    };

DoubleMeanVar& DoubleMeanVar::operator+=(double x){
    m+=x;
    v+=x*x;
    return *this;
}
```

And when i run it, i have this error :

```
error: ‘void DoubleMeanVar::operator/=()’ must have exactly one argument
```

at the line :

> error: ‘void DoubleMeanVar::operator/=()’ must have exactly one
>   argument

I don't understand why, I defined the operator /= as a method, it it shouldn't need argument.

Comment: What will you divide by if you don't take an argument?

Comment: It's just to see how the operators are doing. I thought we could overload the operator any way we wanted, but obviously that's not the case. Isn't it?

Comment: All binary operators need two arguments. That's what "binary" means.

Comment: Thank you both, I understand

Answer (score 3):

Even if you don't use it, there *must* be one (and *only* one) argument for the `/=` operator. In your case, you can declare it like this (unused arguments don't need names):

```cpp
    void operator/=(double){m = 1; v = 0;}
```

Though why you would *want* the `/=` operator to do that is a mystery to me.

Comment: Thank you ! It is just a curiosity from me !